# Installing grounded light fixture on box with no ground conductor

Tags: wiring, grounding

I'm installing a brand new motion activated security light to an existing box on my garage. After removing the old light, I notice it only has white/black wiring while the new light fixture has of course white/black/green (ground) wires to attach. What do I do if no ground wire is available with the old box?

Comment: Have you tried searching the site? I'm pretty sure this has been answered many times before.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few options.

### No grounding conductor

If there's no grounding conductor at all, there's a few things you can do.

#### Install a grounding conductor

Obviously, you could install a grounding conductor for the circuit.

#### Share a grounding conductor

Code allows you to share a grounding conductor from another circuit, as long as the grounding conductor is properly sized.

#### GFCI protected

If you're replacing a fixture, you don't need a ground if the outlet is GFCI protected.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 4 Equipment for General Use
>
> #### Article 410 Luminaires, Lampholders, and Lamps
>
> **410.44 Methods of Grounding.** Luminaires and equipment shall be mechanically connected to an equipment grounding conductor as specified in 250.118 and sized in accordance with 250.122.
>
> ***Exception No. 3:** Where no equipment grounding conductor exists at the outlet, replacement luminaires that are GFCI protected shall not be required to be connected to an equipment grounding conductor.*

### Grounding via conduit or cable covering or ground in box

At times, metallic boxes are grounded using metallic conduit, or the outer covering and/or internal bonding strip of armored cable. If this is the case, then the box may actually be grounded.

There's also a chance that there's a grounding conductor stuffed in the back of the box.

#### Extend the grounding conductor

If the box is grounded, you can simply connect a grounding conductor to the box. If  there's a grounding conductor stuffed in the box, you can simply connect to it.

Comment: If there is no ground available  (because it wasn't required by code when it was installed), is it acceptable to install the fixture without a ground, or does code require that it be  grounded?

Comment: @Johnny No. A **new** fixture must be grounded.  There are exceptions for **replacement** fixtures, but not for new installations.

Comment: I think this *is* a replacement fixture, he said he removed the old light and didn't find a ground wire.

Comment: @Johnny Sorry I missed that.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The box might be grounded on the back. If there's any slack in the cable you might see a ground with a flashlight. I usually wire-up & screw-in an outlet so I can put my outlet tester on to confirm or deny a ground.